# remote:true - submit button works but this.form.submit not

Tags: ruby-on-rails-6

I have form_with form, i want to send the data by Ajax remote:true request.

**What works:**
- when i click submit button, everything is fine, i receive an alertbox (this is what i've put in my .js.erb file)

**What doesn't work:**
- i have search form with many fields, i want to submit form when any of the fields is changed. Without ajax it works fine, the code *"onchange="this.form.submit();"* works perfectly.
But when i use Ajax, this.form.submit() is still reloading the page.

**Expected results:**
- When i change any field, it will send data without reloading page. If it is possible, i want to avoid regular Ajax and use remote:true form_with method.

**What i've tried**
- i've used many jquery variations f.e.:

```
this.form.submit();
$('#id_of_submit_button').click(); // it works but i want to make it without using submit button
$(this).closest("form").submit();
```

**My code:**

show.html.erb

```
<%= form_with(url: "/cars/" + @car.id.to_s + "#formcarsection", id: "filterform", remote: true, method: "get") do |f| %>
  <%= f.text_field :vin, onchange: "this.form.submit();", class: "form-control" %>
  <input type="submit" id="submitbtn" value="Count" class="car__submit-btn">
<%= end %>
```

cars_controller.html.erb

```
def show
  respond_to do |format|
    format.html
    format.js { render 'cars/show.js.erb' }
  end
end
```

cars/show.js.erb

```
alert("Hello! I am an alert box!!");
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `remote: true` needs to be added to each field.

```
<%= f.text_field :vin, data: { url: "/cars/" + @car.id.to_s + "#formcarsection", remote: true, class: "form-control" } %>
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, i know this method and i will use it of course, but i am looking for more "Rails" version of this task. Ruby on Rails has a helper which is sending data through Ajax without writing jquery - it is called "remote: true"

Comment: Does this work? i.e., adding the remote attr to the field itself: `<%= f.text_field :vin, data: { url: "/cars/" + @car.id.to_s + "#formcarsection", remote: true, class: "form-control" } %>`

Comment: This is the answer ! I've added remote:true not only to form_with but also any field in my search form - it's required cause i am submitting form using onchange on those fields. Could you maybe edit your first answer? I will accept it as a resolution then :)

Comment: Edited my answer :-)